# Raspberry PI Model 3 B: Why is the run breakout activated by touching of wire?

Tags: pi-3, reboot

When I touch the RUN breakout square whole with a wire it is activated and resets from shutdown. The other end of the wire is not in contact with anything, and thus surely is not grounded?

Why does this occur? The RUN breakout requires grounding of the square connector in order to reset, does it not?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Could the cable be grounded?
Any clarification would help!

Comment: Your body is probably grounded.

Comment: In that case, would it not reset without contact from a wire? It would be grounded constantly?

Comment: Are you always touching the wire?

Comment: I'm holding it by the plastic coating.

Comment: If you touch the  wire and it resets the Pi I have no other explanation.

Comment: The wire isn't grounded by me if I'm not touching the metal itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  The facts suggest you are completing the circuit when you touch the wire.  Static electricity perhaps.

Comment: I was wondering how I could complete a circuit when there is the plastic coating between my hand and the wire ?

Comment: You need to pose that question on an electrical engineering site.  They could give chapter and verse.